# Mysql hand machine due to high load average and CPU

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqld, mysqld-safe

[image: Snapshot of High Load average]

Mysql is used by only one application which only fire query periodically.
When i restart server,It run smooth for period of time.
and then crash the whole server.

My my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
set-variable = max_connections=200
log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log
safe-show-database
query_cache_size=128M
join_buffer_size=50M
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
table_cache=10K
long_query_time =10
open_files_limit=50000
table_open_cache=20000
table_cache=20000
query_cache_limit=134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_size=900M
```

[mysqld_safe]

```
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: "Crash the whole server" - Does the OS have a `swappiness` setting?  If so, what is it, and how much swap space is allocated.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, it seems you are running on a machine just under 4GB of RAM. You also have ~4GB of SWAP space that MySQL could use if necessary. A rough calculation of how much memory your settings will allow is ~11.5GB.

From mysqlcalculator.com: 
[image: mysqlcalculator.com estimate]

Due to the complex nature of memory allocation, this is an estimate of a worst-case scenario only.

Out of the box, your [`join_buffer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) is extremely large. This is a per-session thread that can be allocated multiple times in a query:

> For a complex join between several tables for which indexes are not used, multiple join buffers might be necessary.

I recommend setting this back to the default (in 5.6, that is 256kb). If you find many queries that are starting to show 'join_buffer' in the explain plan, then you should examine them for better index usage. If that fails, you might consider increasing `join_buffer_size` at the SESSION level for specific queries.

Comment: No.  You are not using 11GB.  Not even close.  That formula (and all others I have seen) are gross overestimates.  And that particular one is an underestimate since it fails to allow for multiple tmp tables from all connections.

Comment: Of course it's not an accurate formula. In addition to your point, it doesn't allow for multiple join buffers. However, it is useful to illustrate a very rough worst-case scenario. And with a `join_buffer_size=50MB` it is a viable reason why "When i restart server,It run smooth for period of time. and then crash the whole server."

Answer (score 1):

> table_open_cache=20000
>   table_cache=20000

Rarely does anyone need more than a few hundred for `table_open_cache`.  `table_cache` is no longer used.

High CPU (or load average) is almost always caused by lack of indexes or poorly written queries.  Turn on the slowlog and set long_query_time = 1; then see what shows up in the slowlog.

Or, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to see what is currently running.  Then let's discuss them.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.